# Accessing an audio file in the RAW folder

Tags: android

I have created a new Java file within my project and i am trying to access a war audio file in my Raw folder. Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 Context context;

 public Audio()
  {

    int resID =   context.getResources().getIdentifier("morse","raw",context.getPackageName());

    context.getResources().openRawResource(resID);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, resID);

}
```

Comment: context seems to be null

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to start the media player. Try the following code,

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 Context context;

```
public Audio()
  {

    int resID =   context.getResources().getIdentifier("morse","raw",context.getPackageName());

    context.getResources().openRawResource(resID);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, resID);
    //start the media player
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Hope it helps!!!...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code and it would not work - i received a run time error 'Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo' on the int resID line. The is class is not an Android activity but it a java class, i could run similar code within an activity and it worked so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Add your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The error is occurring because the activity is attempting to make an instance of this Audio class and cannot do so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

> int resID =   context.getResources().getIdentifier("morse","raw",context.getPackageName());
>
> context.getResources().openRawResource(resID);
>   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, resID);

Try This:

> mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Your_Activity_Name.this,
>                   R.raw.Audio_File_Name);
>         mediaPlayer.start();

Answer (score 0):

- Rename your audio file to `.mp3` or `.wav` or some other audio formats.
- Add your audio file to raw folder in res, `res/raw/audio.mp3`.
- Clean your project.
- Use the following:

  ```
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
  mp.start();
  ```